# Mint "cow format specified as overlayfs and no support found" error

Tags: usb-drive, livecd

On a Mint 19 Mate pen drive persistent setup, I attempt to copy the casper-rw persistent file limited to 4GB to an ext4 partition.

I am looking for the steps to transfer applications and data to an xt4 casper-rw partition and boot it from the pendrive.

Steps so far:

I have created an ext4 partition named casper-rw

I copied all casper-rw files using `rsync -r -p -o -E`

I removed casper-rw from the pendrive.

I rebooted counting on the ext4 casper-rw partition getting priority over the casper-rw file. The ext4 casper-rw partition appeared as casper-rw but was accessed as /casper-rw1.

On reboot there was one "cow format specified as overlayfs and no support found" error.

A second reboot brought Mint back with the ext4 casper-rw partition now mounted as casper-rw while the casper-rw file partition was also accessible.

On the next reboot expecting to boot using the ext4 casper-rw partition, "cow overlaysfs" again.

Removing the casper-rw file or backtracking to a previous casper-rw saved file resulted in the same error.

casper-rw ext4 partition could not be renamed by Windows EaseUS Partition Master. Using SystemRescueCd iso loaded on YUBI I was able to use gparted to change the ext4 casper-rw partition name.

Now I am back up with the casper-rw file mounted.

What I can try to move forward?

`casper package 1.394
ubiquity-casper 1.394
lupin-casper 0.57build1`

Comment: Some persistent live systems work only with a casper-rw **file**, not a casper-rw **partition**. Try with [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb): install mkusb and let it create a casper-rw partition (by default in the same drive as its system). Later on you can create another partition with an `ext` file system, give it the label `casper-rw` and rename or remove the original casper-rw partition (in the same drive as its system). You can also create a home-rw partition (with the label `home-rw`), which will store the modifications (files, tweaks etc.) of your home directory.

Comment: Thanks. I put on the back burner the idea of booting from a pendrive with a casper-rw ext4 partition. The express purpose was avoiding writing onto either the SSD MBR or partition boot sector. The 4GB casper-rw file got gobled up by a 2.6GB /var/logs directory. The pendrive / disk partition solution is probably worth exploring further. I'd recommend a complete install to an external SSD for switching from another OS to Linux rather than trying to push the limits of the pendrive setup.

Comment: I have good experiences of both installed linux systems (like installed into an internal drive) and persistent live linux systems in external SSD drives :-)

Comment: @sudodus Probably worth trying another clean install. Which distro did you get the casper-rw ext4 partition to work?

Comment: It works with mkusb and the Ubuntu family (standard Ubuntu and the community flavours), Debian, Linux Mint (and some other distros that are similar enough to them). Tell me the **name of the iso file with Linux Mint** that you are using, and I can test if it works.

Comment: Mate edition. Thanks for trying. More odds for it to work than not, due to a couple of hard shutdowns.

Comment: I tested with linuxmint-19-mate-64bit-v2.iso and mkusb makes a working persistent live drive from this iso file too. This iso file and the cinnamon version have the same linux kernel version and I would guess that the boot systems and casper systems are the same too. So I think you will manage to make a persistent live drive too. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded `linuxmint-19-cinnamon-64bit.iso` last July, and [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can make a persistent live drive from it. I tested right now (using the default settings) with a Sandisk Extreme 16 GB USB3 pendrive.

You can see in the screenshot that the data of the root partition is the same as the `casper-rw` partition according to `df`. This indicates that the persistence works.

[image]

It is possible to grab more of the available drive space for persistence. If you select 100%, there will be no `usbdata` partition with NTFS.

[image]

Comment: The use case remains to install applications and data on casper-rw file then create an ext4 casper-rw partition, transfer applications and data, finaly boot from the ext4 partition.

Comment: mkusb creates a casper-rw partition directly. There will be no casper-rw file. So you need not transter anything unless you want a casper-rw partition in another drive (for example an internal drive).

Comment: Thanks. When I get around to it, I will copying everything to ext4 casper-rw then in terminal try `update-grub` to see if it will generate a new menu option to boot into the casper-rw ext4 partition. If not I can try to update the grub package following steps in https://itsfoss.com/solve-error-partition-grub-rescue-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: There is an option in mkusb to backup the `/home` directory and to restore it to a new casper-rw partition. Do **not** copy the whole content of the current system's casper-rw file to a new casper-rw partition, because it will probably fail (the system will probably not work after that). This means that your personal files and tweaks (stored in `/home`) can be copied, but you must re-install installed program packages and global tweaks (if any). `update-grub` is made for installed systems, do **not** use it here (except for very special cases, when you know that it works).

Comment: That's a great feature to know about. The use case is about moving from a liveCD to a usable production environment. This is a great step towards it.

Comment: Moving the entire install direct to a casper-rw partition provides in my view a promissing Linux adoption path. There is an order of risk magnitude between a) giving an install process like mkusb permission to write to my production SSD, kwowing it will modify the boot process and b) providing a free partition on the SSD, a risk I am willing to take.

Comment: 1. You should **not** write with mkusb to your production SSD, because it will grab (overwrite) all of it; 2. But it can be a good idea to let mkusb write to another (maybe internal, maybe external) SSD, just like it were a USB pendrive; 3. So I think you are right, try to copy to a free casper-rw partition (or leave it blank) and start over with the configuration. You can copy the files you want later on, including tweaks in your home directory.

Comment: Why does mkusb need control over an entire drive when a full install manages with a free partition?

Comment: mkusb was made to create a live or persistent live system, primarily in a USB pendrive or memory card. Later on it is also used to create a persistent live system in an SSD. -- The idea was never to install a full system or compete with the normal installed systems, and even less to create dual boot systems in one single drive. This is possible, but mkusb must do its thing first, and after that the partition table can be edited to create space for other (live or installed) systems. And these things must be done manually.